Why can't I call Run from asyncio twice in the same function?
I am using Celery to process background tasks in my application. Sometimes, I need to process asynchronous functions within those tasks, for which I use asyncio. And in this case, I also need to process an asynchronous function in a finally block. So my code is something like this:
@celery_app.task(name="charlie-search-engine-task", retry_backoff=True, acks_late=True, max_retries=5)
def search_process(
    order_priority: str,
    subject: str,
    content: str,
    comments: str,
    attachment_names: str,
    recipients: List[str],
    user_ids: List[int],
    department_ids: List[int],
    current_user_id: int,
    temporal_search_id: int
):
    print(f"params: {order_priority}, {subject}, {content}, {comments}, {attachment_names}, {recipients}, {user_ids}, {department_ids}, {current_user_id}, {temporal_search_id}")
    try:
        """
        attachments will be send to searching elk if all params has been received
        because it's meaning users are searching in all params
        """
        search_params = SearchDefault(
            order_priority=order_priority,
            subject=subject,
            content=content,
            comments=comments,
            attachment_names=attachment_names,
            recipients=recipients,
            user_ids=user_ids,
            department_ids=department_ids,
            current_user_id=current_user_id,
            temporal_search_id=temporal_search_id
        )
        log.info(
            f"[INFO]: A process of SEARCHING was started. PARAMS: {search_params.dict()}"
        )
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        asyncio.run(execute_match_search(search_params=search_params))
        stop = timeit.default_timer()
        #log.info(f"Execution Time: {stop - start}")
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(
            f"Error in task for searching with temporal_search_id: {temporal_search_id}"
        )
        log.error(e)
        log.error(traceback.format_exc())
    finally:
        asyncio.run(deliver_message_service.emit_notification(
            notifier=NOTIFIER,
            action=ActionCodes.NO_MORE_RESULTS.value,
            room=search_params.current_user_id,
            channel="search-engine",
            info={},
            title=f"No more found for search {search_params.temporal_search_id}",
            temporal_search_id=search_params.temporal_search_id,
        ))

In the test executions I have done I have not had any errors with the execute_match_search function, so when it finishes executing it goes to the finally block, where I get this error:
Event loop is closed

I have a feeling that maybe it is due to calling asyncio.run twice in the same function. Why does this happen? What options do I have to solve it?

Have you considered moving all your logic into just one async function (and having it do an await instead of an asyncio.run for the two others)? That way we don't need to worry if there's state shared between the two separate ones that could have the latter trying to use something created with the event loop from the former.

I don't think I could, I need the finally block to be executed whether or not the try/except block fails.

Related question: How to combine Celery with asyncio

I don't see why that would stop you from following my suggestion. The finally  block should go in the new function.

Or well maybe I just need to put what is in search_process in an async function and that's it. I'll try and come back

Yes, I simply had to do that. That's how it was solved. Now, is this a specific case, or in general should I never call asyncio.run() twice in the same function?

I'd need a reproducer I can run myself to work out why the latter function is trying to interact with the loop used for the former one -- it's one of those things where context matters.
